# SQL (TSQL) - Select values in a column where another column is not null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I will keep this simple- I would like to know if there is a good way to select all the values in a column when it never has a null in another column.  For example.

```
  A      B
-----  -----

  1      7
  2      7
NULL     7
  4      9
  1      9
  2      9
```

From the above set I would just want 9 from B and not 7 because 7 has a NULL in A.  Obviously I could wrap this as a subquery and USE the IN clause etc. but this is already part of a pretty unique set and am looking to keep this efficient.

I should note that for my purposes this would only be a one-way comparison... I would only be returning values in B and examining A.

I imagine there is an easy way to do this that I am missing, but being in the thick of things I don't see it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select *
from t
where t.b not in (select b from t where a is null);
```

If you want only distinct b values, then you can do:

```
select b
from t
group by b
having sum(case when a is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

And, finally, you could use window functions:

```
select a, b
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when a is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by b) as NullCnt
      from t
     ) t
where NullCnt = 0;
```

Comment: That second example works really well for my purpose!  I should note that all of this is a part of avoiding relational division.

Answer (score 1):

The query below will only output one column in the final result. The records are grouped by column `B` and test if the record is *null* or not. When the record is *null*, the value for the group will increment each time by 1. The `HAVING` clause filters only the group which has a value of `0`.

```
SELECT  B
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY B
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

If you want to get all the rows from the records, you can use join.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  B
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY B
            HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
        ) b ON  a.b = b.b
```